# const return type in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

```
const Byte operator/(const Byte& right) const {
    require(right.b != 0, "divide by zero"); 
    return Byte(b / right.b); 
}
```

I read that *If the effect of the operator is to produce a new value, you will need to generate a new object as the return value. For example, `Integer::operator+` must produce an `Integer` object that is the sum of the operands. This object is returned by value as a `const`, so the result cannot be modified as an lvalue*.

What if we don't write it as `const`? Any example with explanation would be helpful.

Also why do we have second `const` in function prototype?

Comment: The first `const` is no longer recommended.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned, you should typically implement `operator/` by calling `operator/=`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any example with explanation would be helpful.

This is outdated advice, intended to make the operator behave somewhat like the built-in operator so that nonsense like `(a / b) = c` won't compile.

However, since C++11, it also inhibits move semantics, which can hurt efficiency; so you shouldn't return a `const` value.

> Also why do we have second const in function prototype?

The argument is a `const` reference, and the member function is `const`, to (a) ensure that the operator doesn't modify either operand; and (b) allow it to be called with constant or temporary operands.

To elaborate on (b), without these `const` qualifiers, you wouldn't be able to use constant operands:

```
const Byte a, b;
a / b;  // ERROR: operands can't be const
```

or temporary values:

```
Byte f();
f() / f();  // ERROR: operands can't be temporary
```

Comment: could you please explain (b) in your ans?

Comment: @debonair: OK, I've added some examples of trying to apply the operator to constant and temporary values.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: "However, since C++11, it also inhibits move semantics, which can hurt efficiency; so you shouldn't return a const value." Could you please explain this line please?

Answer (score 1):

For *binary* operators, I'd prefer defining a "free" (non-member) function (that may be `friend` of the class on which it operates, in case it needs to directly access the `private` or `protected` data members of the class):

```
class Byte {
  ....

    friend Byte operator/(const Byte& left, const Byte& right) {
        require(right.b != 0, "divide by zero"); 
        return Byte(left.b / right.b); 
    }
};
```

Both `left` and `right` parameters are passed by `const &` because:

- they are *read-only* input parameters, so mark them as `const`
- you don't want to make useless deep-copies (assuming that they are not cheap), so use reference `&`

Anyway, if your `Byte` class just wraps an 8-bit byte, and the copy constructor is a trivial one-byte copy, you can simplify your code and just *pass by value*:

```
friend Byte operator/(Byte left, Byte right) {
    require(right.b != 0, "divide by zero"); 
    return Byte(left.b / right.b); 
}
```